# How to apply Test Driven development for GUI application(VC MFC)?

Tags: user-interface, mfc, tdd

Can I use TDD for gui application?
How to do it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The answer which has evolved over the last few years is, *you don't apply TDD to the GUI, you design the GUI in such as way that there's a layer just underneath you can develop with TDD.* The Gui is reduced to a trivial mapping of controls to the ViewModel, often with framework bindings, and so is ignored for TDD.

This is known variously as the [Presentation Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html) (Fowler) the [Model-View-ViewModel](http://blogs.msdn.com/johngossman/archive/2005/10/08/478683.aspx) and [DataModel-View-ViewModel](http://robbbloggg.blogspot.com/2008/04/datamodel-view-viewmodel-in-wpf-part-1.html) architecture.

This approach removes the GUI layer from TDD and unit testing. It does not mean the GUI is never tested but just acknowledges that it is not cost effective to pursue automated GUI testing, particularly as part of TDD. Integration and user testing should cover the GUI.

Josh Smith's [2009 WPF article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) is a detailed explanation of MVVM with some testing.

More recently, Houssem Dellai's [2016 video Creating Unit Tests for Xamarin Forms Apps](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/MVP-Windows-Dev/Creating-Unit-Tests-for-Xamarin-Forms-Apps) shows a XAML UI with bound ViewModel and walks through creating a unit test project

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  Note, though, that the link to `good discussions` is pretty much useless - it points to a search for ViewModel which is a massive area that includes a huge number of discussions that have nothing to do with TDD.  Links to specific discussions would be useful.  I have been digging into this topic heavily over the past few days and there is sadly little discussion of this issue.

Comment: When I wrote my answer, 8 years ago, that search was indeed a good one but it was a bit silly to expect it to stay that way.

Answer (score 5):

Why not. [Here](http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/category/testing-guis) is a good article, from [object mentor](http://objectmentor.com/).

Found another blog post, [TDD - Introduction to Moq](http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/2008/06/11/tdd-introduction-to-moq.aspx). Its related to C# and VB.NET.

Checking out [Myth and Misconception](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/tdd.html#Misconceptions) regarding TDD is a must.

Here is a book related to .NET, [TDD in Microsoft .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619484).

Answer (score 1):

Chad Myers has a nice walk through testing the controller:

http://www.chadmyers.com/Blog/archive/2007/11/27/tdd-with-asp.net-mvc-3.5-extensions.aspx

Comment: Link is dead. You should really copy the gist of the content into your answer for the answer to stay relevant over time...